# Print more than one result in SQL Data Reader

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

I have a Stored Procedure that will return more than 1 value from a table. However, I'm only able to print 1 result, can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong

vb.net Code

```
reader = cmd_loadMacro.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()
        MacroKey = reader.GetString(0)
        MacroValue = reader.GetString(1)
```

My query does return results when i execute it SSMS, I should have 5 rows back, but only 1 row is returned

Latest attempt  (This brings 0 results back)

`reader.Read()

```
        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                MacroKey = reader.GetString(0)
                MacroValue = reader.GetString(1)
            End While
        End If`
```

Comment: you could always read the documentation, which has samples. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and another... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: while loops shows no results

Comment: update your code in the question to reflect the latest attempt. are you sure your query will return results?

Comment: Have you tried getting the values then using .NextResult()?

Comment: How are you determining that you are getting no results? have you tried setting a breakpoint, and stepping through your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to working using a for loop in my main class, and passing it on to the function. This works perfectly.

```
MacroKey = reader.GetString(0)
                MacroValue = reader.GetString(1)
                writer.WriteStartElement("djmacros") ' Root.
                writer.WriteStartElement("macro")
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", MacroKey)
                writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "1000")
                writer.WriteAttributeString("value", MacroValue)
                writer.WriteEndElement()

                While reader.Read
                    MacroKey = reader.GetString(0)
                    MacroValue = reader.GetString(1)
                    writer.WriteStartElement("macro")
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", MacroKey)
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "1000")
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("value", MacroValue)
                    writer.WriteEndElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `If reader.HasRows Then` bit that surrounds your loop and try it again.

I've had problems with reader.HasRows in the past returning unexpected results.

Comment: While loop shows no results at all. If i execute the code with out any "if" or "while" statements i will get 1 row back, i would like to get all 5.

Comment: @aridi - You have to call `Read` for each row.  That's why you need a loop.

Comment: @aridi Please can you update your question with all of the relevant code.